Process for identifying why a query slows down during times of heavier activity
I'm still a bit of a newb when it comes to troubleshooting and diagnosing issues with slow-performing queries in SQL Server.
Basically, there is a query that runs throughout the day as users pull information related to sales orders.  Generally, this runs very quickly.  I'm noticing that as stored procedures pertaining to unrelated reports are running on the same SQL instance (typically taking a few minutes to complete), this sales order query takes longer to complete.  Indeed, a number of transactions seem to be taking longer and we end up with a a bit of a logjam for a few minutes until the report stored procedures complete.
A few notes on what I've already looked at:

We have lots of processing power and memory available to the SQL server.  I'm not seeing high CPU on the server, and max memory is set to allow the OS to still have several GB to work with.

We're using premium SSDs for both the data drive and the log drive.

There is plenty of disk space.

We have a max degree of parallelism of 4 (with a total of 16 CPUs, all of which are online according to the sys.dm_os_schedulers table) and a cost threshold of parallelism of 50 (the latter is recommended by the app vendor) for a 200gb database.

We have 8 TempDB data files (and one log file) stored together on their own premium SSD drive separate from the data and log drives.  8 TempDB files was the Microsoft recommendation during installation.

Our SQL instance is hosted on a VM in Azure.  The move from on-prem to Azure was fairly recent.  Problems do appear to have worsened since the move to Azure, but these problems have always been there with this SQL server to some degree.

It appears our most common wait types on this SQL instance throughout the day are ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION (24%), CXPACKET (17%) and CXCONSUMER (16%).

While there are times where queries are getting blocked by another query, making it more clear what the issue is, this doesn't appear to be the case in this instance (these queries appear to be read only, though they may populate temp tables or CTEs used only within the scope of that sproc or view).  I'm trying to understand these situations in which a few unrelated queries that are reading data appear to impact one another performance-wise.


I'm not expecting anyone to know and provide the definite solution for this issue, as I haven't offered much information and I understand it would require research to explore the nuances.  I'm more interested in some guidance as to what I should be looking into next given these symptoms.

I noticed that you were not monitoring the disk load. You assumed that the performance of the SSD is good enough without data to back it up, but ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION doesn't look too good, so I recommend monitoring the performance of your disk.

Hi Rodger, you're right that I haven't turned my attention to disk load monitoring yet with regard to this issue.  Another member of the team oversees that and they aren't seeing any issues from that standpoint.  What kinds of indicators should I be looking for to help with identifying that the disk is underperforming or inadequate?  What sort of solutions would we be looking for if that proves to be the case?  I appreciate any guidance you can offer!

I think you're on the right track, wait statistics, database diskfile latency, blocking would be the most common ways to diagnose a problem like yours. Try looking at Paul Randals blog where he has scripts for calculating wait stats and file stats over a short period of time & then run these when the problem is actually occurring.

Instead of wait statistics try to capture wait during slow executions, i.e. look at sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks wt
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
on wt.session_id = s.session_id

Check this document, it descripts how to troubleshoot I/O issues of SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-sql-io-performance

If you want to directly test the disk's performance, you can check with CrystalDiskMark.

Have you tried recording the parameters call for the queries and then rerunning on a test system that replicates live ? Do you get the same issues ? Do you have a parameter sniffing issue leading to the ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION ?

After enabling on-demand bursting through Azure, we saw noticeable improvement with the performance of our queries during heavier activity.  It appears our Azure configuration was limiting the throughput and causing I/O issues during heavier periods.
